# Connect deepstream server to rethinkdb instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb, deepstream.io

I have tried to set up a deepstream.io instance but ran into some difficulties:
I don't know how to connect the deepstream.io instance to the rethinkdb server. I tried this condiguration:

```
//rethinkdb connector
  server.set( 'storage', new RethinkDbConnector({
  port: 28015,
  host: '104.155.51.222',
  splitChar: '/',
  defaultTable: 'users'
}));
```

However, the server crashes after the start and puts out:

```
PLUGIN_ERROR | storage wasn't initialised in time
```

although I opend all the ports needet (8080 and 28015) and kept the instace running via tmux.

Do you have any idea how to fix this? I would really appreciate an answer, thanks in advance!

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Hm - looks like a connectivity issue between the machine that deepstream.io is running on and your RethinkDB machine. Just tried accessing 104.155.51.222:8080 in a browser and it timed out. Could you try

a) if you can access the admin gui
b) if you can ping 104.155.51.222 from your deepstream machine

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer! I was yersterday able to solve it by adding `rethinkdb --bind all`  to the start command and using the eth0 adress to connect to it from the deepstream server.

However, there is now one more pressing issue I ran into: I am trying to connect the client-side sample code provided in the tutorial to a remote server who is already wired up for production. But once I connect to the server the chrome dev tools show something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj0BY.png).

The deepstream server is running with the following configurations:

```
server.set( 'host', '0.0.0.0' );
server.set( 'port', 6020 );
```

Do you have an idea what went wrong? Anyways,thank you for your awesome work at deepstream.io, I really appreciate it!

Comment: It looks like a network latency issue. Similar problem I presume - deepstream is struggling to connect. Can you see the incoming connection attempt in your deepstream console?

Also, I don't think that this is a deepstream specific problem. Could I invite you to join the [deepstream Slack channel](https://deepstream-slack.herokuapp.com/) for more immediate support.